# Can I say “We went to the same middle and high school”?

Tags: coordination

I made this sentence and I want to shorten it.

> We went to the same middle school and the same high school.

Can I shorten it like this?

> We went to the same middle and high school.

Or maybe like this?

> We went to the same middle and high schools.

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer the [plural ***schools***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22went+to+the+same+middle+and+high+schools%22) rather than [singular ***school***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22went+to+the+same+middle+and+high+school%22) in such contexts. But as you'll see if you follow those links, I'm very much in the minority on that point. I don't think it makes any difference to the choice of plurality whether you delete the predictably repeated words ***the*** and/or ***same***.

Comment: ...or indeed if you *don't* delete the predictably repeated preposition: *We went to the same middle school and **to** the same high school.* Come to that, you don't have to delete anything at all: *We went to the same middle school and **we went to the same** high school.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though they use two words, "middle school" and "high school" each refer to a single entity, and you would typically use the two words together. So the most common way to shorten it would be:

> We went to the same middle school and high school.

In spoken English, you can get away with *middle and high school*, but it's definitely less common and it's also incorrect (should be plural). However, it would be rare to hear someone use the plural (correct) form in speech. Go figure.

Comment: The spoken versus written English point here is good.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I see no problem with this.

There is an ambiguity introduced: You may be referring to two schools a Middle School and a High School, or you may be referring to a single school that you both attended. This single school covers grades 6-12 and is called a "Middle and High" school.

But the communication point is that you knew this person throughout your teenage years, so whether the schools are combined is irrelevant to communication, and so the ambiguity causes no problem.

So you can say this by omitting the repeated elements.